# Putting ads in PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, preferencescreen

Im trying to put admob ads in my preferencescreen. I have looked around and i've found a few threads about this. Though i can't get i working. For example this:

[Android Admob advert in PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019834/android-admob-advert-in-preferenceactivity?lq=1)

You have an activity as is supposted to be the launcher activity? 
Ain´t that activity supposted to be connected with the ad_layout.xml file in any way?

In my own application I have a class that extends PreferenceActivity, and in that way i can launch my preferencescreen with this line:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
```

Where should I do that in the "Admob in PreferenceActivity" example, linked above?

Im sorry if it got a bit unclear, in that case, please ask! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out how they were connected. Used this example to understand: [How do I create one Preference with an EditTextPreference and a Togglebutton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738658/how-do-i-create-one-preference-with-an-edittextpreference-and-a-togglebutton)